# Android Http request ClientProtocolException

Tags: android, rest, http-post, http-request

I have an API that seems to be working perfect when I test it using Firefox's "REST Client" or Google Chrome's "Simple REST Client"
However, when I send an Http request using Android SDK I get the following exception:

ClientProtocolException: the server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response

also when I test using Google Chrome's "Advanced REST client" I got an empty response, so any idea about what might be causing this ?

`DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Constants.URL);

httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

StringEntity se = new StringEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);

httpPost.setEntity(se);

httpClient.execute(httpPost);`

Comment: any luck? I'm having a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct.

`ClientProtocolException` happens if there is an `INVALID REQUEST` from the client or an `INVALID RESPONSE` from the server

Also you have specified `httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");` it expects that the server is returning an `JSON` response. See [docs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for more details.

So you may check what response you are sending from the server. It should be a JSON response.

Or you can try removing `httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");` and check what response you are getting.

Comment: can you post your server side code and give some example of what you are trying to send and what you want to recieve

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
HttpParams httpParams=new BasicHttpParams();
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Constants.URL);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
httpPost.setEntity(se);
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: Didn't change anything