# unsupported exception in android

Tags: php, android

I am creating an android app that allows the user to upload items that they wish to sell to a server by running a php script on said server I am passing parameters to the PHP scripts via namevaluepair

but I am getting an error that says

> - Unhandled exception type IOException
>
>   - Unhandled exception type
> - ClientProtocolException

these errors appear after the point I try to add more parameters to the array

```
Btn_Submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                byte[] data;
                HttpPost httppost;
                StringBuffer buffer;
                HttpResponse response;
                HttpClient httpclient;
                InputStream inputStream;
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

                String ItemDescription = TxtItemDescription.getText().toString();
                String ItemTitle = TxtTitle.getText().toString();
                String StartTimeAndDate = TxtStartTimeAndDate.getText().toString();
                String StartPrice = TxtStartPrice.getText().toString();

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

                    protected Double doInBackground(String...  params){
                        return (Double) null;
                        }       
                    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://www.albarrett.co.uk/PS_Auctions/test.php");
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", ItemDescription));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", ItemTitle));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", StartTimeAndDate));


                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

                data = new byte[256];

                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                int len = 0;
                while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data))) {
                    buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len));
                }

                inputStream.close();
            }
}
        });
```

Comment: You can't do network IO on the main UI thread.  You have to do it on a Thread or AsyncTask.  Also, make sure you have all the needed permissions.

Comment: added async but still getting the same errors

Comment: forgot to mention I also had clientprotocolexception error as well which according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296451/android-http-request-clientprotocolexception

is a http error

Answer (score 0):

Unhandled does not necessarily mean that an error is thrown, but that you need to do something in case it is thrown.

You can do this with try/catch. If you use eclipse, you can click the error and automatically apply this, of course you can also do this manually:

```
try {  
    .. your code that might throw something ..
} catch(IOException ex) {
    //writes to your log
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can replace `IOException` with any other exception or use `Exception` to catch any exception.

**Note:** By the way, prevent networking on your main thread in case you do so.

Comment: yh eclipse recommended putting a try catch around it so I did that figuring it would give more information... will be happy if it doesn't throw an error :)

Comment: It doesn't necessary has to throw one, you just have to catch it in case it does (no internet etc).